# Using hostname output in linux with sed

Tags: sed, output, hostname

I am trying to use part of the hostname output in Linux and use it in a file using sed. For example, I am using this command as
hostname |tail -c 4 which shows me output as last 4 numbers and then use this output and substitute it with another text inside a file.

Assuming part of the hostname command shows with tail -c 4 option, "1234" How can I take it this further and use it to replace it with another file. I can do this manually by:

hostname |tail -c 4 ; sed -i 's/oldtext/1234/g' filename.txt

but not sure how can I achieve this with script? Any ideas?

Comment: If using bash, which is common on Linux but not universal, it already provides the hostname in `$HOSTNAME` and `${HOSTNAME: -4}` gives the last 4 chars. zsh similarly has `${HOST: -4}`. (Note the space is required to disambiguate from the POSIX default-if-unset-or-null syntax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the output of the first command in a variable

```
$ var=$(hostname |tail -c 4)
```

Once stored, you can then use it as the replacement with `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak "s/oldtext/$var/g" filename.txt
```

Comment: It works! thanks so much